# Display PDF in Report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to display dynamically .pdf files like pictures in a report, it should look like this:

[image]

i already tried with webbrowser, but then it doesn't show up in the preview or when i print the report out...

I also tried a ole unbound object, also no success, here the code i had in the `Report_Load` event:

```
Dim vPath As String

vPath = GetNewestDocument(Me!artNr)
'Returns path for pdf file, about:blank if there is no file.
If vPath = "about:blank" Then
        Me!PDFBrowser.visible = True
        Me.PDFBrowser.SourceDoc = vbNullString
Else
        With Me.PDFBrowser
        .OLETypeAllowed = acOLELinked
        .SourceDoc = vPath
        .SizeMode = acOLESizeStretch
        End With
End If
```

**EDIT:**

With "I want to display dynamically ..." i meant to change dynamically pdf's in the Report.

**EDIT 2:**

I just found out that the type of the OLEunbound object is embedded, but i think this one should be linked as i read in other Forums: [image]

When i try to Change it gives error: "This property can not be changed because it is read-only"

Comment: can you get it to work with a hyperlink to the pdf instead of an embedded object?

Comment: If I create a new report, add an unbound object frame and select a pdf, it works just fine. Having set that, have a look at this discussion: [Embedding PDF file in Report](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/embedding-pdf-file-in-report.3261155/)

Comment: How "dynamic" are these PDF images?  Is there a limited number of PDFs?  How many? You want to programmatically choose which one to display? -- or, are they being generated on the fly by another program?  No interaction is required with the PDF (like filling a PDF form), correct?  Are they single-page PDF's?  Are they all the same dimensions?  Do you have the full version of Adobe Acrobat (not reader)?  Do you have an issue with using 3rd-party or possibly "unlicensed" software to make this happen?  Does this need to work on only *one* installation of Access?

Comment: ....I assume you've posted the bounty since you're already aware (as a little research shows) that what you want to do is ***not possible*** through *"traditional"* means... (ie., [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/use-pdf-as-access-report-background/9591c5d5-95e0-409f-b855-26e3dea089d1).) That being said, "there's always a way".  I have a couple ideas depending on your answers to the above clarifications.

Comment: @Beth Hyperlink does also not change the pdf on the Form load/open Event - also no error.

Comment: This is getting confusing. What has the report to do with a `Form_Load` event? Do you want to change the displayed PDF *in an already opened report?*

Comment: @Andre much sorry, i meant in the Report_load event of course

Answer (score 3):

You could get a licensed version of [Adobe Acrobat](https://www.amazon.ca/s/keywords=adobe+acrobat) (not Reader) and control it programmatically to capture the images you want.

Alternatively, you could use the VBA [`Shell Function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function) to call a command-line PDF converter like [2Jpeg](https://www.2jpeg.com/) to programmatically (and dynamically if necessary) convert the PDF to an image (see [this](https://www.print-driver.com/stories/convert-pdf-to-jpg-via-the-command-line)), or even "print" the PDF to an image file using the correct driver (see [this](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/software-reviews/extract-images-from-pdf-files/)).

Once you have an image file, you can easily load the created image to your Access form with VBA, perhaps with [this](http://www.lebans.com/loadsavejpeg.htm).

Without further information (and answers to my previous questions) I can't offer more suggestions at this point but I hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Sir, i already heard from the 2jpeg method, but this would also be the  most consuming Way for displaying a one Page pdf, i thought there can be a other way

Comment: The oleunbound does already display the pdf, but i cant load others on the form load/open/current event

Comment: how you mean set number of Images? this are all pdf's

Comment: what i don't get is that on the create of the oleunbound object i can choose the PDF and it also got correctly shown

Comment: but i cant change it with the vba code above, there are also no errors, the first PDF just stays in.

Comment: @JulPod -- You didn't mention in your question that you need to change anything.

Comment: "I want to display dynamically .pdf files ..."

Comment: "Display", not "Change"

Comment: Do you mean to switch to different pictures, or to change, as in edit the picture?

Comment: You can switch to as many pictures as you want if you are producing them dynamically with the  suggestions above.  Editing the images is not possible, at least not without a major amount of coding.

Comment: no i dont want to Change anything at the Images, i just want to load different pdf's on the form load or open Event with an oleounbound object

Comment: or other object as somebody knows